# Rails 3.2.x Undefined Method 'join'

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a basketball app with a many-to-many relationship where a Coach could have coached multiple teams, and a team can have many Coaches.

**Coaches_Controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @coaches = Coach.joins(:teams).select("coaches.first_name, coaches.last_name, teams.team_level")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @coaches }
    end
  end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<% @coaches.each do |coach| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to coach.first_name, coach_path(coach) %></td>
        <td><%= coach.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= coach.team_level %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_coach_path(coach), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      coach_path(coach),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
                      :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

I am getting this error, and I'm not quite sure why...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a6oB.png

Ideas? I feel like it is something small I'm not seeing... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I can see that is wrong is that you don't have `coaches.id` in your `select`. You need the `id` for `coach_path(coach)` to work. Try this:

```
@coaches = Coach.joins(:teams).select("coaches.id, coaches.first_name, coaches.last_name, teams.team_level")
```

Not sure if this solves the `join` error you are getting.

Comment: ahhh fiddle sticks, I knew it was something easy I over looked. Thanks for making me feel dumb buddy ;P